# dispatch_queue_t DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL in react native ios project objective-C not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, react-native, avfoundation

I want to call a delegate method of class `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`. Implementation as below,

```
//Protocol inheritance
  @interface QRScannerVC : UIViewController<AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>{

//Code of delegate assignment of AVCaptureMetadataOutput
capturedMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_captureSession addOutput:capturedMetadataOutput];
capturedMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode];
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("qrQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
//Delegate method assignment
[capturedMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];

Delegate method,
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray<__kindof AVMetadataObject *> *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    if (metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count > 0) {
        
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObject = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        
        if ([[metadataObject type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
            
            [_labelStatus performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObject stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];
            
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            _isReading = NO;
        }
    }
```

As per [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemetadataoutput/1616309-setmetadataobjectsdelegate?language=objc) `capturedMetadataOutput:setMetadataObjectsDelegate:queue` method must be call on the serial queue for continuous streaming. And as per [react native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.html#threading) we can invoke our method if operation take long time to complete.

But in my case `capturedMetadataOutput:setMetadataObjectsDelegate:queue` method not calling. If i use same code in pure iOS native Objective-C project then it will works good.
Doesn't get what is is an issue in React native.

Comment: We are sure that `_captureSession` is not nil, and that `QRScannerVC`, which I guess holds it is not deallocated? Is it declared `@property(strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *captureSession`?

Comment: @Larme, i don't know what is an issue. But this issue occur's in various lib's for example react-native-vision-camera. I post this issue on official git support page https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/41031 but not reply.

Comment: @Larme, i after searching i found one more lib react-native-camera-kit worked well using same code but only difference every where is https://github.com/teslamotors/react-native-camera-kit/blob/master/ios/ReactNativeCameraKit/RealCamera.swift ... Tesla put entire camera session in a queue.